# Show help message onFocus of Edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to show some help text(much like in a webpage when a field is focused a non-modal popup is shown about what to enter in the field).

I have used `android:hint` attribute of EditText but that clips the text if it is long. Is there any built in or quick way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a TextView below your EditText that contains the hint. By default set it to be invisible.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="your hint message..."
/>
```

Now add a onFocusChangeListener to make the TextView visible / invisible:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            tvHint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            tvHint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a `TextView` just below the `EditText`. Implement the `onFocusListener` of the edittext and when the edit text has focus set the textView visibility to View.VISIBLE which will display the help text. And when the edit text loses its focus make the textview invisible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Custom Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156304/show-help-message-onfocus-of-edittext-android) massages or [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for non-modal popup like web see these likes help u creating custom Toast and popupwindow

https://github.com/quiqueqs/Toast-Expander/blob/master/src/com/thirtymatches/toasted/ToastedActivity.java

http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/

and use  `OnFocusChangeListener` Listener for tracking when user clicked on EditView or when leavening focus

```
txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
               //show Toast massages or PopupWindow     here           
        }
    });
```